# How to make a JSP website accessible in LAN / INTRANET

Tags: jsp, web, lan, intranet

Does anyone know how to actually make a JSP website project accessible in a LAN.

I am using Netbeans and the built in Glassfish server to test my project. I run XAMPP Apache to run the interface for the DBMS and MySql for the database itself.

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

A JSP Application for LAN should be fine without Apache / Xampp. The reason is that Apache is highly optimized for static files and your GlassFish server should not take the burden.

You could change the Container HTTP Port (look at Glassfish's Documentation) in the server configuration or in some cases, you may need to enable it.

Change the port from 8080 to 80 & ensure that the firewall settings are ok.

You should be good to go.

If you need to work with Apache, then use Tomcat & use Mod_JK to make the Apache - Tomcat bridge.

Comment: can you please tell me how i'd run my project using the server? or where i need to place my files for the server to run the project?

and would it automatically run the project on a certain port such that when other computers put the server's ip address on their browser it will automatically run/refer to the project?

Comment: my glassfish server is built in netbeans. would that work fine?

ill look into a separate glassfish server for the project.

i needed XAMPP for connection to mySQL database. :)

Comment: Stick to Basics, Install Tomcat, its lightweight & you could figure out how to port it to Glassfish later. in the WebApps forlder, create a Folder with your App Name eg MyApp, Then place all your JSP files here. Your Classes should be in MyApp/WEB-INF/classes and you JAR files in MyApp/WEB-INF/lib. Restart the server & you are ok.